# How to keep TextBox's "IsFocus" property from changing to "false" when button is clicked ...?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a problem with my mvvm project. I want to enter a value for each textbox, how do I know which textbox I am going to enter a value for?
I use backgroud to know which textbox is in focus. for example I want to enter the value 12 into textbox1, I will click on textbox1 and click on button1 and button2, the "content" property of textBox1 will be 12, (note I don't use the edit cursor, and I have many textBox). but when the button is pressed, the "IsFocus" property of the textbox is changed to "false" (I think). (I am just starting out and my English is not that good). Here is my xaml code.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RedTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="RosyBrown"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="DataView" ItemsSource="{Binding Mydata}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}" Margin="0,0,0,73.667" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Text="TextBoxA" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="TextBoxB" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"></TextBox>
    
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="1" FontSize="25"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="2" FontSize="25"></Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope to receive your comments!

[image]

Comment: Looks like XY problem. What are you try to reach? Generally, your textboxes should be bonded to model's properties, so you will know which textbox was changed.

Comment: I would be happy if you give me a simple example. how to know which textbox is "focus" when the button is pressed. Like I would have to check all the textbox when a button is clicked. Thank you very much! <3

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you focus TextBoxA, enter a value, then click button 2?

Comment: No `TextBox` is indeed focused when you click on the button. Maybe you want to know the last focused one? Or what do you want?

Comment: i can not using keyboard. I can only use buttons to enter numeric data, like a pocket calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your requirement, but:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="DataView" ItemsSource="{Binding Mydata}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems}" Margin="0,0,0,73.667" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
        <TextBox Text="TextBoxA" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="TextBoxB" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="1" FontSize="25"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="2" FontSize="25"></Button>
</Grid>
```

The idea here is to create focus scope, meaning scope within which the logical focus traverses. Other words, if you wish to keep one of the text boxes to keep focus while button receives focus, both: text box and button must belong to different focus scopes.

Does it answer your concern?

Answer (score 0):

**.xaml**

```
    <TextBox Text="TextBoxA" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" 
             FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" 
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBoxMouseDown"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="TextBoxB" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBoxStyle}" 
             FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" 
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBoxMouseDown"></TextBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="1" FontSize="25" 
            Click="ButtonClick"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="2" FontSize="25" 
            Click="ButtonClick"></Button>
```

**.cs**

```
    TextBox last;

    private void TextBoxMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        last = (TextBox)sender;
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (last != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(last.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this violate mvvm?

Comment: Indeed :) Right MVVM-way will be to have a some property in a model, which is designated to store the last control that user clicked. Or it is required to re-think about architecture at whole. If you build a some kind of calculator, for instance, it is not required to know last control that user touched, it is required to know *a value* that user entered the last.